# Google App Engine app.yaml URL Mapping

Tags: google-app-engine

So a part of the app.yaml file looks like the following (on the GAE tutorial at least):

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

However, I've also seen it look like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /*
  script: main.py
```

Is the second one wrong? Why is the "." necessary and what does it notate? And why does the script end in ".app" when it is clearly a ".py" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.* is a regexp that matches everything.  Do a google search on regular expressions.  main.app is the notation for the wsgi apps for python 2.7.

main.py is probably for a python 2.5 app.

Comment: Yes, for the .app suffix check the Python 2.7 App Engine docs.

Answer (score 3):

.app is not the file extension! main.app means the app object from main.py;
the app object must be a WSGIApplication object

main.py:

```
import webapp

def HwHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       self.response.out.write('Hello world')

appvar = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', HwHandler)],debug = True)
```

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.appvar
```

Comment: Oh wow, I've been interpreting this wrong for a while then. Thanks for clearing that up, it makes sense now.